# Average geodesic distance over all connected graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request

For $G$ a connected graph with vertices $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ the geodesic distance $d_G(i,j)$ is the length of the shortest path between vertices $i$ and $j$.

I'm looking for a bound of
$$ 
\sum_{G \text{ connected}} \prod_{1\leq i < j\leq n} d_G(i,j)^2.
$$
In particular, is it $\leq C^{n^2}$?

The intuition is that "most" connected graphs have "most" vertices close together, so that for "most" vertices $i$ and $j$ we have that $d_G(i,j)\leq C$.
Then $\prod_{i < j} d_G(i,j)^2$ should be of order $C^{n^2}$, and as there is also $\leq 2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ many connected graphs, this would give the bound $\sum_G \prod_{i<j} d_G(i,j)^2 \leq C^{n^2}$.

Comment: Do you have an idea of the graphs that maximize $\prod_{1\leq i < j\leq n} d_G(i,j)$?  One that seems pretty bad is the tree you obtain by starting with a path of length $n/3$, and attaching $n/3$ leaves to each of the two ends (roughly speaking).  The product of $d_G$'s is at least around $(n/3)^{(n/3)^2}$.

Comment: That indeed shows that the bound $\leq C^{n^2}$ is false. For any graph $d_G(i,j) \leq n$, so worst case for a single graph is $\sim n^{n^2}$. Your example shows that such graphs exist. Thanks!